# How do you make a modular SCSS file without having ".module" in the file name?

Tags: reactjs, sass, module

I work full time as a front-end developer and all the sites I've worked on have components with a style.scss file in it. The component imports it with `import style from './style.scss';` and the `style` object has all the classes in the .scss file and they are renamed so that only this component will be styled by them.

So the issue I have is that I've tried doing the same thing. I have a pretty fresh React app opened up (typescript), I installed node-sass, added a style.scss file into one of my component folders, added some classes, and imported it into the component .tsx file with `import style from './style.scss';`. Well, to my sturprise, this doesn't work. And the only way i got it to work was to rename `style.scss` to `style.module.scss`. I've looked around and can't seem to find anyone talking about this issue. How come all the websites I've been working on do not need to include "module" in the file name but I have to include it.

Is there any solution to this problem witout ejecting?

Comment: Try naming it `_style.scss`

Comment: It still doesn't work. It would if i was importing it into a scss file, but I'm importing it to a .tsx file